# Why and when must we need to add "[Serializable]" attribute？

Tags: serialization

1) Besides for serialization from an object into a file/memory…… When must we add "[Serializable]" attribute?

2) Why must we add that? Why cannot we directly save the object into some known formation to the .NET library?

3) How can I tell in what sitatuations we must add this attribute? In what conditions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Besides for serialization from an object into a file/memory…… When must we add "[Serializable]" attribute?

When you want to serialize it, or an object that contains it, directly or indirectly, to any other medium, e.g. a socket, RMI, ...

> 2) Why must we add that?

Because that's the way they designed it. Security reasons spring to mind: you really don't want a password to be serializable by default for example.

> Why cannot we directly save the object into some known formation to the .NET library?

Firstly because Serialization preceded .NET by several years; secondly there are various other ways of accomplishing that, such as SOAP.

> 3) How can I tell in what situations we must add this attribute? In what conditions?

You're just re-asking the same question here, two more times. You certainly need to do it if you ever get a `NotSerializableException` naming the class and the exception didn't indicate an inadvertent serialization of something you didn't intend to serialize in the first place.